# How to call queue client sendasync method using C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I have created an azure service bus and I've created a shared access policy, see screen shot below.  From this screen I click 'overview' and then 'queues' which is shown below.  Using the connection string and queue name from these screens within the C# code below I'm not able to successfully call the following line of code (complete code sample included below)

```
await queueClient.SendAsync(message);  // This line of code eventually times out.
```

Is there some further azure permissioning or C# code change I'm missing?

Many thanks,

**Policy/ connection string**

[image: primary connection string]

**Queue screen**

[image: name of queue]

**complete code**

```
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BasicSendReceiveQuickStart
{
    class Program
{
    static IQueueClient queueClient;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string serviceBusConnectionString = "Endpoint=sb://abc123.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xyz";
        const string queueName = "name_of_my_queue";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceBusConnectionString) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(queueName))
            MainAsync(serviceBusConnectionString, queueName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Specify -ConnectionString and -QueueName to execute the example.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }                            
    }

    static async Task MainAsync(string serviceBusConnectionString, string queueName)
    {
        queueClient = new QueueClient(serviceBusConnectionString, queueName);

        Console.WriteLine("======================================================");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit after receiving all the messages.");
        Console.WriteLine("======================================================");

        // Register QueueClient's MessageHandler and receive messages in a loop
        RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages();

        // Send Messages
        //await SendMessagesAsync();

        var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("my message"));

        await queueClient.SendAsync(message);


        Console.ReadKey();

        await queueClient.CloseAsync();
    }

    static void RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages()
    {
        // Configure the MessageHandler Options in terms of exception handling, number of concurrent messages to deliver etc.
        var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
        {
            // Maximum number of Concurrent calls to the callback `ProcessMessagesAsync`, set to 1 for simplicity.
            // Set it according to how many messages the application wants to process in parallel.
            MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,

            // Indicates whether MessagePump should automatically complete the messages after returning from User Callback.
            // False below indicates the Complete will be handled by the User Callback as in `ProcessMessagesAsync` below.
            AutoComplete = false
        };

        // Register the function that will process messages
        queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
    }

    static async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // Process the message
        Console.WriteLine($"Received message: SequenceNumber:{message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber} Body:{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");

        // Complete the message so that it is not received again.
        // This can be done only if the queueClient is created in ReceiveMode.PeekLock mode (which is default).
        await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);

        // Note: Use the cancellationToken passed as necessary to determine if the queueClient has already been closed.
        // If queueClient has already been Closed, you may chose to not call CompleteAsync() or AbandonAsync() etc. calls 
        // to avoid unnecessary exceptions.
    }

    // Use this Handler to look at the exceptions received on the MessagePump
    static Task ExceptionReceivedHandler(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs exceptionReceivedEventArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Message handler encountered an exception {exceptionReceivedEventArgs.Exception}.");
        var context = exceptionReceivedEventArgs.ExceptionReceivedContext;
        Console.WriteLine("Exception context for troubleshooting:");
        Console.WriteLine($"- Endpoint: {context.Endpoint}");
        Console.WriteLine($"- Entity Path: {context.EntityPath}");
        Console.WriteLine($"- Executing Action: {context.Action}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
}
```

**Overview panel showing requests**

[image]

Comment: Could it be a networking issue? Can you see the request being created and hanging?

Comment: It's a good question but I've just included the request graph within the azure service bus portal and it shows requests just now which is strange to me, if it was a networking issue between me and azure..  Unless you mean networking within azure, i.e. ip and general azure access/ permissioning perhaps?

Comment: I am on a VPN but wouldn't the fact the requests are shown in the graph mean this isn't a problem?

Comment: If you test with debug mode, could you see the message in the service bus queue?

Comment: And if `await queueClient.SendAsync()` could not work, please try `queueClient.SendAsync(message).Wait()`. Also make sure the port 80 and 443 are open or try with `ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Https;`.

Comment: where do I check and correct the ports?

Comment: adding `.Wait()` produces the `cannot await void` compiler error

Comment: Don't use `await queueClient.SendAsync(message).Wait();` only `queueClient.SendAsync(message).Wait();`. And did you try the ConnectivityMode.

Comment: Yes I have but same issue strangely..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203641/discussion-between-george-chen-and-james).

Answer (score 0):

.Net 8. You now need to create a sender...

```
namespace ServiceBusSender
{
    using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
    using System.Text;
    class Program
    {
        const string ServiceBusConnectionString = "Endpoint = sb://yournamespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=blahblahdEnw9DikgO72pF/+ASbENh/24=;QueueName=queue1";
        const string QueueName = "queue1";
        public static ServiceBusClient queueClient;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        }

        static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            const int numberOfMessages = 10;
            queueClient = new ServiceBusClient(ServiceBusConnectionString);
            var sender = queueClient.CreateSender(QueueName);
            await SendMessagesAsync(sender,numberOfMessages);
            await queueClient.DisposeAsync();
        }

        static async Task SendMessagesAsync(Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusSender sender, int numberOfMessagesToSend)
        {
            try
            {
                for (var i=0; i<numberOfMessagesToSend; i++)
                {
                    //create a new message to send to queue
                    string messageBody = $"Message {i}";
                    var message = new ServiceBusMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));
                        //write to console
                    Console.WriteLine($"Sending message: {messageBody}");
                    //send to queue
                    await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} And error occured");
            }
        }
    }
}
```